# PyTorch differentiation at non-differentiable values

Tags: pytorch

I'm implementing an L1 penalty term to regularize a loss function using PyTorch. Since the L1 regularizer is not differentiable everywhere, what does PyTorch do when it encounters differentiating this functions?

A simple example shows PyTorch returns zero.

```
import torch

x = torch.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 5, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.abs(x)
y[2].backward()

print(x.grad)
```

> ```
> tensor([-0., -0., 0., 0., 0.])
> ```

Why is this the case? Is PyTorch using a specific algorithm to compute this? Is there an academic reference that discusses this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I have very limited experience with PyTorch, but I found [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html) to help me understand what I believe is going on here.

PyTorch does not perform analytic differentiation, so while `y[2]` would be a non-differentiable corner for your absolute value function in an analytical sense, it is still computationally differentiable for the context of your example.

I don’t know the specific algorithm used, but I’m sure if you read the docs or source code you could figure it out. My best guess is that, for your code example, `y[2].backward()` will assume various changes to `y[2]` and work backward to see what the necessary changes would need to be for each value in `x` to achieve each of those changes in `y[2]`. There are a few different methods to achieve this with linear algebra.

You’ve correctly noticed that `x.grad` contains nothing but 0 values. This is because `y[2]` is dependent solely on `x[2]`, so all other values in `x` render 0 change in `y[2]`, and `x[2]` is itself 0, so when multiplying `y[2]` by some constant there is no corresponding number by which to multiply `x[2]` because 0 is the additive identity, and addition makes for a tricky problem because `y[2]` as 0.01 could mean `x[2]` is either 0.01 *or* -0.01, so there’s no clear-cut, obvious rate of change for that linear operator.

**TLDR:** You are experiencing a side effect of an implementation detail for a computational algorithm meant to emulate differentiation. PyTorch does not perform analytical differentiation. The approximations it performs will not always be 100% correct, as evinced by your example.

Hope that helps,

—K